# block a direct call to a controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm working on a website using JAVA Spring mvc. I have a functionality that requires two controllers. First of all, the request is handled by controller1 who redirect it to controller2 using a return new ModelAndView ("redirect:controller2.htm"). All is working fine. However,I would like to block the direct access to the controller2 ( block a call from the  url "controller2.htm") because the controller2's form needs data from the controller1.I want that the only case in which controller2 is used is the redirection from controller1. I would like a solution without annotations.Thanks in advance for your help.
Here is the code :
Controller1:

```
public class controller1 extends SimpleFormController implements Serializable {
private PersonManager pManager ;   
@Override
public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) {
    CommandPerson cmd = (CommandPerson) command;
    Person p = null;
        String viewName = "redirect:controller2.htm";
        try {
            p = pManager.getPersonbyID(cmd.getID());
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
      viewName="NosuchPerson";
        }
       ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(viewName);
        mav.addObject("ID",cmd.getID());   
        return mav;
 }
```

controller2:

```
  public class controller2 extends SimpleFormController implements Serializable {
    private PersonManager pManager ;   
    @Override
    public ModelAndView onSubmit (Object command) throws ServletException, IOException { 

          Person p = (Person) command;
         Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                pManager.UpdatePerson(p);
                model.put("person", p);
               return new ModelAndView("SuccesfulUpdate","model",model);

        }

    protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
             throws ServletException, IOException {
                        String  id = request.getParameter("ID");
                        if(id==null) {
                            response.sendRedirect("controller1.htm");
                            return null;
                        } else{
                    Personne p = pManager.getPersonbyID(id);
                          return p;
                }}
```

If the url "controller2.htm" is called directly the ID parameter will be null,and as the formBackingObject() is the first method executed when the request is being handled I thought I could  make a redirection in it , but it didn't work as I'm redirected to the controller2's form being empty.

Comment: A redirect causes the _browser_ to issue the request for the redirect URL. How would you expect to make this differentiation?

Comment: There are too many ways to solve this. Perhaps the simplest is to restrict access at the network level.

Comment: the functionality is an update functionality.There is a first form in which the user fill the form's field with an id , then the first controller check if the object with the specified ID exists in the database . if it exists there is a redirection to the second controller which use the ID to extract the object from the database and then uses the formBackingmethod() to fill the second form with the  current values of the object. I just want to block the direct access to controller 2 because if the user call directly the url "controller2.htm" from the browser he won't get a pre-filled form.

Comment: Can you show the code for redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I overrided the showForm method . In this method , I could test if the parameter exists in the request . If it exists the formBackingObject method is called and the controller2's form is displayed else there is a redirection to controller1.

Controller1:

```
 public class controller1 extends SimpleFormController implements Serializable {
private PersonManager pManager ;   
@Override
public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) {
    CommandPerson cmd = (CommandPerson) command;
    Person p = null;
        String viewName = "redirect:controller2.htm";
        try {
            p = pManager.getPersonbyID(cmd.getID());
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
      viewName="NosuchPerson";
        }
       ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(viewName);
        mav.addObject("ID",cmd.getID());   
        return mav;
 }
```

Controller2:

```
 public class controller2 extends SimpleFormController implements Serializable {
        private PersonManager pManager ;   
        @Override
        public ModelAndView onSubmit (Object command) throws ServletException, IOException { 

              Person p = (Person) command;
             Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    pManager.UpdatePerson(p);
                    model.put("person", p);
                   return new ModelAndView("SuccesfulUpdate","model",model);

            }

        protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
                 throws ServletException, IOException {
                            String  id = request.getParameter("ID");
                            if(id==null) {
                                response.sendRedirect("controller1.htm");
                                return null;
                            } else{
                        Personne p = pManager.getPersonbyID(id);
                              return p;
                    }}

     protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors)throws Exception {
        String id = request.getParameter("ID");
    if (id==null) return new ModelAndView("redirect:controller1.htm");
    else{
            Personn p = (Personne) formBackingObject(request, response);
        return new ModelAndView("UpdatePersonForm","Person",p);
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very near to the Cross Site Request Forgery protection, so the same general solution should apply.

You just have to generate a random token in `Controller1`, put it in model under an arbitrary name (say `"_csrf"`) and also store its value in session. Then in `Controller2` you test that :

- the parameter request `_csrf` is present in request
- it is equal to the value stored in session

and immediately remove the `_csrf` value from the session.

If both requirements are met, it is highly probable that `Controller2` was called via a redirect from `Controller1`, as nobody else should be able to guess the value

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Actually ,I want to prevent the direct access to controller2 wih the url "controller2.htm" . So , I don't know if that would be possible or not , to redirect the request to "controller1" wehenever the "controller2.htm" is called directly from the browser.I want to make the controller2 dependant to controller1 so calling "controller2.htm" will be as if we called "controller1.htm" because the update functionality requires being handled by controller1 then controller2.So, it's preferable to block direct access to controller2 as it must also be used after controller1.